# If $u$ is harmonic and bounded in $0 < |z| < \rho$, show that the origin is a removable singularity

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

*This is a reworking of a previous question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/458474/ux-y-harmonic-and-bounded-in-punctured-disc-show-0-is-a-removable-singula) which was marked as a duplicate. Some nice folks have referred me to solutions to similar problems. I still have a couple of questions, since one of the solutions used the Poisson kernel, which is not the desired solution in the text, because the Poisson kernel has not been introduced yet. The other solutions were for problems that were similar, but whose solutions were only partially applicable, as I understand them.*

I'm working on a problem from p. 166 of Lars Ahlfors' *Complex Analysis*:

> If $u$ is harmonic and bounded in $0 < |z| < \rho$, show that the origin is a removable singularity in the sense that $u$ becomes harmonic in $|z|<\rho$ when $u(0)$ is properly defined.

**My Solution So Far:**

Here's what I've got for a non-Poisson kernel solution: We want to find a harmonic conjugate for $u$ in the punctured disk, and then we can apply big Picard to show that $0$ is a removable singularity. The problem is that the punctured disc is not simply connected.

If we take $\sigma = (u \circ \exp)(z): L \to \mathbb{C}$, where $L$ is the left half-plane, now we have $\sigma$ harmonic, and defined in a simply connected set $L$, so it has a harmonic conjugate $\tau$. Now we wish to take $v = (\tau \circ \log):\{0 < |z| < \rho\}\to \mathbb{C}$, but in order to do so we need $\tau$ to be $2\pi i$-periodic. This is where my proof breaks down.

One of the similar problems which readers referred me to used the following strategy: note that since $\sigma$ is $2\pi i$-periodic, and $\sigma, \tau$ satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations, we have that $\nabla\tau(z) = \nabla\tau(z + 2 \pi i)$ for all $z\in L$, or in other words, $\tau(z) - \tau(z+2\pi i)$ is a constant function, say, equal to $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. Then, the solution suggests, we can set $$g(z) = u + iv - \frac{c}{2\pi}z,$$

in order to make $g$ $2\pi i$-periodic, and then we can use $(g\circ \log)$ on $\{0 < |z| < \rho\}$. But the reason why this won't work for my purposes is: now we have changed $u$! On the other hand, we can't simply subtract $\frac{c}{2\pi}\Im{(z)}$, and try to leave $u$ untouched, because now $g$ is not analytic. How can we get around this?

Another strategy entirely might be to try to use the mean-value property. Ahlfors discusses that a lot in the preceding section, and his main example is the punctured disc. Since $u$ is harmonic, we know that the average over circles centered at zero is a constant...

Comment: It's been a while, but I recall having the exact same question when I took complex analysis. (The Poisson kernel idea didn't please me either...) Here's an outline of what I think is the intended solution: Suppose you want to find a harmonic conjugate. You do this by integrating. Over simply connected regions, your choice of integration path doesn't matter, so the value is well-defined. But here, it's possible it isn't well-defined: circling around the puncture might add stuff. So let $I$ be the integral of the function around the puncture.

Comment: By subtracting I times $\log r$ (times some appropriate constant), you get a harmonic function where the integral around the puncture is zero. Then you can find a harmonic conjugate and form an analytic function...

Comment: Oh, this sounds very promising...thanks @Potato !

Comment: I'm missing some essential details and probably misremembering things, but I'm sure something like that will work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is proof based on the contents of the book until that point:

Theorem 20 in the text states that for $0<r<1$ $$\frac{1}{2 \pi} \oint_{|z|=r} u\, \mathrm{d} \theta=\alpha \log r+\beta $$
Where $\alpha=\oint_{|z|=r} r \frac{\partial u}{\partial r} \, \mathrm{d} \theta=\oint_{|z|=r}*\mathrm{d}u$. ($*\mathrm{d}u=-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \mathrm{d} x+ \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \mathrm{d} y$ is the conjugate differential.)

Let us take $r \to 0^+$ in the theorem: since $u$ is bounded the integral on the left tends to zero, and therefore the $\log$ term must have coefficient zero. So that $\oint_\gamma *\mathrm{d} u$ is zero for every circle with radius $0<r<1$. $|z|=\frac{1}{2}$ is such a circle, and in fact it is a *homology basis* for the punctured disk. Thus the integral $\oint_\gamma * \mathrm{d}u$ vanishes for every cycle $\gamma$ in the punctured disk, and we can define a harmonic conjugate $v$ there.

The function $f=u+iv$ is analytic in the punctured disk, and it has bounded real part around $z=0$. According to exercise 5 on page 130 we find that the singularity at $0$ is removable, so that we can extend $f$ to an analytic function in the whole disk, and $u$ is extended harmonically that way.

Comment: why is it that if $\int_{\gamma}*du = 0$ for any cycle $\gamma$ then $u$ has a harmonic function there?

Comment: Oops,I meant to say harmonic conjugate.

Comment: @CuteBrownie That is because it allows you to define a function $v$ with partial derivatives $v_x=-u_y, v_y=u_x$ via indefinite integration.

Comment: could you elaborate as an answer to my question (click on my profile)? I made a separate question for this inquiry.