# Why is it that for a hamonic $u$, $\int_{\gamma}*du = 0$ for any cycle $\gamma$ then $u$ has a harmonic function there?

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions, analytic-functions

> Let $u$ be a harmonic function on a connected open set. If $\int_{\gamma}*du = 0$ for any cycle $\gamma$ then $u$ has a harmonic function.

This question arises from an answer to [this post](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/459134/if-u-is-harmonic-and-bounded-in-0-z-rho-show-that-the-origin-is-a-re&ved=2ahUKEwiRzPjTr-neAhWRDHwKHZ3nAV0QFjAAegQIBhAB&usg=AOvVaw3nm6JShLZJqBzyv7t77q65)

Please do modify this question's assumptions if I am not stating some things correctly.

We know that the converse is true, namely that for any harmonic $u$ on an open connected set that has a harnonic conjugate, $\int_{\gamma}*du = 0$. I am thinking maybe Morera's theorem has to do something with this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest looking at this from a real calculus of two variables perspective.
You are given that
$$\int_\gamma -\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \mathrm{d} x+\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \mathrm{d} y \equiv 0, $$
for all cycles $\gamma$ in the domain. This allows you to safely define a function
$$v(x,y) := \int_{(x_0,y_0)}^{(x,y)} -\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \mathrm{d} x+\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \mathrm{d} y . $$ with $(x_0,y_0)$ a fixed point in the domain. The expression for $v(x,y)$ is well defined, since the difference between any two integration paths is a cycle.